# Convert rows to columns - querying from same table

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that's getting data from the same table. The first query gets data that have the status "Paid" while the second query gets the invoice for the current month.

First Query (Gets previous paid invoice):

```
SELECT 
date as 'datePd', invAmt as 'invAmtPd', refNum as 'refNumPd'

FROM inv

WHERE cst = "Customer"
AND status = "Paid"
```

Output of this is:

```
    |   datePd   |  invAmtPd    |   refNumPd    |
    | 11-20-2016 |  1500        |   0001        |
    | 12-20-2016 |  5500        |   0002        |
```

Second Query (Gets the latest invoice for the current month)

```
SELECT 
date as dateCur, refNum as 'refNumCur', invAmt as 'invAmtCur'

FROM inv

WHERE cst = "Customer" AND YEAR(date) = "2017" AND MONTH(date) = "01"
```

Output of this is:

```
    |   dateCur      |  refNumCur    |  invAmtCur   |
    |   2017-01-05   |  0003         |  2500        |
```

I'm trying to achieve this output wherein it will show the columns from the previous query and the data from the current query.

```
    |   datePd   |  invAmtPd    |   refNumPd    |   refNumCur    |  invAmtCur   |
    | 11-20-2016 |  1500        |   0001        |   0003         |  2500        |
    | 12-20-2016 |  5500        |   0002        |                |              |
```

How would be the best way for me to achieve this output?
I tried using UNION but that just resulted into appending the result of the second query to bottom...

Note: The previous paid amounts are dated from last year, while the latest is for 2017, if its possible it would be great if the previous will also be outputted.

Comment: I would just use PHP (or whatever you are coding in) instead of MySQL to get that formatting. There just isn't a great way to do this in MySQL and I don't see any reason you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
SELECT past.date as 'datePd', past.invAmt as 'invAmtPd', past.refNum as 'refNumPd', 
present.date as dateCur, present.refNum as 'refNumCur', present.invAmt as 'invAmtCur'
FROM inv as past
LEFT JOIN inv as present ON (past.cst = present.cst)
WHERE past.cst = "cust1" 
AND past.status = "Paid"
AND YEAR(present.date) = "2017" AND MONTH(present.date) = "01"
```

result comes out like this:

```
datePd     invAmtPd         refNPd  dateCur             refNCur invAmtCur
2016-11-20 00:00:00 1500    0001    2017-01-05 00:00:00 2500    0003
2016-11-20 00:00:00 5500    0002    2017-01-05 00:00:00 2500    0003
2017-01-05 00:00:00 0003    2500    2017-01-05 00:00:00 2500    0003
```